# ElectronJS BrowserWindow.minimize() seems to be broken

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm trying to minimize a fullscreen, frameless BrowserWindow (mainWindow) in ElectronJS 2.0.2 by calling `mainWindow.minimize()` and nothing happens.

If I try to close it by calling `myWindow.close()` it works fine.

- `mainWindow.isMinimizable()` is true
- `mainWindow.isMinimized()` remains false
- no exceptions are thrown

Here is a code sample:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow(
{
  backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
  frame: false,
  fullscreen: true,
  icon: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/icons/png/64x64.png'),
  kiosk: true,
  title: 'Title',
  webPreferences: { session: ses, webSecurity: false },
  width: width, height: height,
});

mainWindow.setMenu(null);
mainWindow.setAutoHideMenuBar(true);
mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

ipcMain.on('minimize-window', () => {
  console.log('is minimizable: ', mainWindow.isMinimizable()); // true
  console.log('is minimized: ', mainWindow.isMinimized()); // false
  mainWindow.minimize();
  console.log('is minimized: ', mainWindow.isMinimized()); // false
});
```

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Can you please show the code you're using?

Comment: Please post the part of the code where you are calling `mainWindow.isMinimizable()`. I don't see any reference to it in your current code.

Comment: I called it right before calling mainWindow.minimize() just for testing purposes.

Comment: using your exact code it's still working as expected. (side note: don't expect `isMinimized` change immediately, it's OS message driven)

Comment: I partially figured out which is the problem. The minimize() is not working only when I'm having a react-modal component rendered in the BrowserWindow. If I close it then it works. I have no idea why is this happening.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what I do is I get the `currentWindow` by:

```
mainWindow.getFocusedWindow().minimize();
```

That's what I do...
Let me know if this works on you